# Arriving at the same model after using different model selection methods

Tags: multiple-regression, model-selection

My full model has 10 predictors, and after using forward AIC and BIC, backward AIC and BIC, step-up, and step-down selection methods (6 total), I arrived at the same model that has the exact same 9 predictors. What can I interpret from this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is this something unexpected in your case?

Comment: I'm not sure how common this is, but the examples that I've seen generally had different models while using the different selection methods. Is there anything to say regarding this occurrence?